# How to get value from multiple different textbox through javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
        function showUser()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var internal = document.getElementById("inte[i]").value;   /* but its not working */
                var external = document.getElementById("exte[i]").value;
            }
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php 
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='internal' id = 'inte[$i]' width='30'/> </td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='external' id = 'exte[$i]' width='30'/> </td>";
        }
        echo "<td><input type='submit' name='submit1' value='Save Marks' width='30'  onclick = 'showUser()' /></td>";
    ?>
    </body>
<html>
```

i am using the above code but i cant get 10 values of different textboxes
how to fetch these value through java script and i want to save it to database kindly help me

i am using the above code but i cant get 10 values of different textboxes
how to fetch these value through java script and i want to save it to database kindly help me

Comment: There is an unclosed comment in the for loop.

Comment: The [i] in the `document.getElementById("intel[i]")` doesn't get reffered to the i. Its is evaluated as find the element with the id "intel[i]" To fix this you would remove the quotes.

Comment: you php for loop is incorrect `(i=0;i<10;i++)` should be `($i=0;$i<10;$i++)`

Comment: @Bala Krishnan view my posted answer

Answer (score 1):

You are not placed `i` value in `getElementById`

Replace your

```
document.getElementById("inte[i]").value;
```

as

```
document.getElementById("inte["+i+"]").value;
```

Make your for loop as

```
for (var i=0; i<10; i++)
{
  var internal = document.getElementById("inte["+i+"]").value;   /* but its not working  */              
  var external = document.getElementById("exte["+i+"]").value;
}
```

Comment: I think he is looking it up in an array defined somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't doing what you think:

```
getElementById("inte[i]")
```

That's just a string, the `i` value doesn't get interpreted into an integer.  This would:

```
getElementById("inte[" + i + "]")
```

Answer (score 0):

When your Javascript for loop runs you are are overwriting your var internal and external each time so after the for loop runs you will only have the last value that was assigned to the  variables. You should use an array and push the values of the text boxes into it.

```
var internal = new Array();
var external = new Array();

for (var i=0; i<10; i++)
{
  internal.push(document.getElementById("inte["+i+"]").value);   /* but its not working  */              
  external.push(document.getElementById("exte["+i+"]").value);
}
```